# Alarmanager - where to put?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm planning to do an alarm app to notify user to return their borrowed dvds based on a set date time on my db. My question is where do I put the alarmanager? Is it in the main activity? or do I need to put it in a separate class?

Answer (score 1):

That's really up to you, and it has less to do with the working of your Application since it is moslty a programming structure/design.

Yes, if you use the `AlarmManager` a lot, and in a lot of places, I would put in another class. But there is nothing 'wrong'  by putting it in your Activity.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Good luck with your app.

Comment: Do you know how to put an array of 2 dates inside an Alarm manager? Do I need to create a separate class for that or can I insert it inside the DoInBackground class?